# Is it possible to exit the command window when Holoviz Panel application browser window is closed?

Tags: python, powershell, terminal, holoviz, holoviz-panel

I am writing an application that uses Holoviz `panel`. After interaction with the application is completed, I close the browser window, but the server remains running in the terminal/command line window.

Is it possible to automatically close the terminal/command line window if the browser tab displaying the application is closed?

For example, here's my app:

```py
import panel as pn
import param


class Test(param.Parameterized):
    test_number = param.Integer(default=0)


test = Test()

app = pn.template.VanillaTemplate()
app.main.append(test.param)
app.servable()
```

When I run it with `panel serve`, I can interact with the application. Once I'm done, I close the browser window. Is there a way to make sure that the `panel serve` command also exits/stops?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What is the "window"? FastListTemplate? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks, the window in this question refers to a Command Prompt (cmd.exe).

Comment: Are you using `serve()` or `show()` to display your app? And sorry for not being specific myself in the last comment. I ment to ask what is the Panel widget your app shows in the browser?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad! I am using panel.template.VanillaTemplate and then filling it with Row/Columns... will update the question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are scripts for shutting down command prompt from Python, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67146623/how-to-close-the-command-prompt-from-python-script-directly) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873212/python-to-close-own-cmd-shell-window-on-exit?rq=3) SO question. This version of your example shuts down the server, but leaves the command prompt window open:

```py
import panel as pn
import param


def interrupt(session_context):
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

class Test(param.Parameterized):
    test_number = param.Integer(default=0)

def main():
    test = Test()

    app = pn.template.VanillaTemplate()
    app.main.append(test.param)
    app.servable()
    pn.state.on_session_destroyed(interrupt)
    return app

try:
    session = pn.serve(
        {"Test": main},
        port=8000,
        title="Test",
        show=True,
        start=True,
        autoreload=False
    )
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I'm sure there is some more elegant way of doing this by using Panel function `stop()` but I didn't manage to get that working. The idea is to put `session.stop()` inside the `interrupt()` function. My environment has some problems with using `threaded=True` as a parameter to the `session`. That would supposedly hasten the process. Now it takes quite some time for the server to stop.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of using the Exception route (via KeyboardInterrupt), very cool! :) FWIW, I couldn't get the threaded version to work either with your example, but that's not an issue for me.